# Pagination in custom web part displaying library

Tags: 2013, web-part, document-library, paging

I have a document library. I am displaying this library using my own CSS in a custom web part. My question is how do I apply pagination?
Normally in ASP.Net we simply use

```
SQL query such as SELECT  *
FROM     sys.databases
ORDER BY name 
OFFSET  5 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
```

to limit the numeber of rows returned based on current page. Is there such a thing in SharePoint when fetching data from list/library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, you'll want to use the `ListItemCollectionPosition` property of SPQuery.

> SPListItemCollectionPosition is the class which helps to achieve
>   paging and sorting the results fetched by SPQuery.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemcollectionposition.aspx

and [here](http://extreme-sharepoint.com/2012/06/22/spquery-pagination/) for a more comprehensive example

Answer (score 1):

Paging using CAML cannot go to a Nth page directly, like you can do in SQL.

For using paging, you need to use ListItemCollectionPosition property in the SPQuery.

### Tips

- Limit the Columns (ViewFields) of your query
- Set the RowLimit on the SPQuery
- Don't forget to explicit the OrderBy in the Query
- Choose an indexed column (if possible) to OrderBy
- Every time you run the query, this property will return the string for the next page, so you pass this on the next query to get the next page.
- I had some issues using PagePrev in my project, even though the CAML was correct, so I've implemented a solution to store the pages in ViewState, then I can go to the next/prev page using "Page Index" (custom property of the Webpart)

If you have further questions, please comment. If not, please accept the answer

EDIT1) References
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/sharepoint-2010-using-splistitemcollectionposition-for-fas/

- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/ro-RO/1ac0cd45-8ba2-439f-b534-bc05573ae33e/sorting-and-paging-with-spquery-at-the-same-time?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy